# How to open files in JAR file with filename length greater than 255?

Tags: linux, windows, jar, filenames, long-filenames

I have a JAR file with following structure:

```
com
-- pack1
   -- A.class
-- pack2
   -- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.class
```

When I try to read, extract or rename `pack2/AA...AA.class` (which has a 262 byte long filename) both Linux and Windows say filename is too long. Renaming inside the JAR file doesn't also work.

Any ideas how to solve this issue and make the long class file readable?

Comment: Show us the code which you se to "read, extract or rename". At least on Linux, it should work.

Comment: @AaronDigulla thank you. What code do you mean? I tried to read, extract and rename by traditional applications like `GNOME Archive Manager`, `unzip`, `jar -xvf`, `7zip`, `WinZIP`, `WinRAR`.

Comment: At least `jar -xvf` should work in Linux. Windows tools probably can't handle it because of the 256 byte limit of file names (1024 for the whole path unless you use some new file API). Which file system on Linux?

Comment: File system on linux is `ext4`. `jar -xvf` doesn't work. It even doesn't show an error message (although `-v` option is given)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.jar` can handle it:

```
try {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("/path/to/target.jar");
    Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntries = jarFile.entries();
    int i = 0;
    while (jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntries.nextElement();
        System.out.println("processing entry: " + jarEntry.getName());
        InputStream jarFileInputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
        OutputStream jarOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/test/test" + (i++) + ".class")); // give temporary name to class
        while (jarFileInputStream.available() > 0) {
            jarOutputStream.write(jarFileInputStream.read());
        }
        jarOutputStream.close();
        jarFileInputStream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JARExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The output willbe `test<n>.class` for each class.

Answer (score 2):

This pages lists the usual limits of file systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

As you can see in the "Limits" section, almost no file system allows more than 255 characters.

Your only chance is to write a program that extracts the files and shortens file names which are too long. Java at least should be able to open the archive (try `jar -tvf` to list the content; if that works, truncating should work as well).

Comment: What a pitty. I wonder if anybody already wrote such a tool which can handle long filenames.

Comment: No, since you normally can't create archives with such long file names. I suggest that you submit a bug report to whoever generates that JAR file.

Comment: I think this is a cleverly usage of a bug because it's in an obfuscated JAR file. I wonder how the obfuscator could rename a class that long and how the JAR packer packed it without problems :-)

Comment: As long as none of these ZIP items ever pass through the file system, you can give them arbitrary names (maybe even with 0 bytes in them).

Comment: Yes I see. JAR files are not meant to be extracted in traditional way. That's why I wondered if anybody already faced this issue and wrote a tool. Thanks for your help!